# How to configure Angular 4 behind Proxy?

Tags: angular, webpack, proxy, angular-cli, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to use angular 4 application behind a proxy server (I'm using zuul as proxy server), since I'm using context path routing, I've configured zuul routes with context path. Below is the zuul routes configuration.

```
kp-app1:
  path: /kp-app1/**
  retryable: true
  serviceId: kp-app1
  strip-prefix: false
```

Since Angular runs with `baseurl=/` I manually edited index.html and added `/kp-app1/`. After much of struggle analyzing packets flow using wireshark, I figured out that though `index.html` is retrieved properly rest of the resources such as `inline.bundle.js, main.bundle.js` did not had the context-path prefixed, when requesting from client to proxy, since there was no prefix, zuul was not able to match url and forward it my angular application. Finally when I build Angular application by passing base-href and deploy url though these issues are fixed. However still for images and Font Awesome I'm getting 404 error.

```
ng build --base-href="//kp-app1" --deploy-url="//kp-app1"
```

On analyzing pcap file. I find still angular client is requesting images with `/assets/myimages.png` instead of prefixing with effective request as `/kp-app1/assets/myimages.png` and for font awesome though it is prefixing /kp-app1 but not adding forward slash in between(`/kp-app1fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2`). Hence for images and font awesome zuul url match does not work, resulting in 404 error

And also I tried to build with different combination of --base-href and --deploy-url and I get different index.html

1. if url is given with `/kp-app1`, for some reason angular-cli is appending git path

   ```
     cmd: ng build --base-href="/kp-app1" --deploy-url="/kp-app1"
     output: <base href="C:/Program Files/Git/kp-app1/">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Program Files/Git/kp-app1/inline.bundle.js"></script> ...
   ```
2. if url is given with `/kp-app1/`, effect would be same as 1.
3. if url is given with `//kp-app1`, When I configure this though it works for js and css file but fails for images and fontawesome.

   ```
     cmd: ng build --base-href="//kp-app1" --deploy-url="//kp-app1"
     output: <base href="/kp-app1">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="/kp-app1/inline.bundle.js"></script> ...
   ```
4. if url is given with `//kp-app1/`.

   ```
     cmd: ng build --base-href="//kp-app1/" --deploy-url="//kp-app1/"
     output: <base href="//kp-app1/">
             <script type="text/javascript" src="//kp-app1/inline.bundle.js"></script> ...
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally I solved the issue. Below are the changes I made.

1. First mistake I was not postfixing the url with `/` that is I was using `/kp-app1` instead of `/kp-app1/`
2. Image was not getting loaded as I was providing relative path in as shown below

   ```
   <img src="../../assets/myimage.png">
   ```

   when I changed it `./` images started getting loaded.

   ```
   <img src="./assets/myimage.png">
   ```

   **Note:** In some post I see we can use `~` instead of `.`, not sure it works I've not tried.
3. Finally problem of appending `C:/Program Files/Git/` when I prefix `/` in `base-href` it seems its a [problem](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5606) with angular cli with `gitbash`. When I used windows cmd it got sorted out. Note I omitted `--deploy-url`. I just used

   ```
   ng build -bh /kp-app1/
   ```